# Python/Django Beginner

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I'm new to web-developing, I get:

IntegrityError at /map/rebuild/

null value in column "snow_Depth" violates not-null constraint

do you see anything I'm doing wrong in this function?
Are my moves illegal?

imports.py:

```
1 from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
2 from models import *
3 from apps.pages.models import *
4 from decimal import *
5 from datetime import *
6 import string
7 
8 def add_points():
9     response = ""
10     all_data_entries = DataEntry.objects.all()
11     point_layers = PointLayer.objects.all()
12 
13     PointLayer.objects.all().delete()
14     size = 1
15 
16     for this_data_entry  in all_data_entries:
17         point_layer = point_layers.create( pk=size )
18         point_layer.albedo = this_data_entry.albedo
19         point_layer.snow_Density = this_data_entry.snow_density
20         point_layer.snow_Depth = this_data_entry.snow_Depth
21 
22         ret = this_data_entry.station_Number
23 
24         if ret == "CH15":
25             point_layer.lat = 43.067657
26             point_layer.lon = 72.218724
27         if ret == "SL8":
28             point_layer.lat = 43.420129
29             point_layer.lon = 72.09098
30         if ret == "RC13":
31             point_layer.lat = 43.0159
32             point_layer.lon = 70.8272
33         if ret == "GR4":
34             point_layer.lat = 44.1467
35             point_layer.lon = 71.965
36         if ret == "CS7":
37             point_layer.lat = 44.49611
38             point_layer.lon = 71.57639
39         if ret == "MR11":
40             point_layer.lat = 43.284896
41             point_layer.lon = 71.92525
42         if ret == "CS11":
43             point_layer.lat = 44.373681
44             point_layer.lon = 71.613242
45         if ret == "MR4":
46             point_layer.lat = 43.149944
47             point_layer.lon = 71.556467
48         if ret == "GR11":
49             point_layer.lat = 43.760317
50             point_layer.lon = 71.688856
51         if ret == "CR1":
52             point_layer.lat = 43.6037
53             point_layer.lon = 70.9867
54         if ret == "ST21":
55             point_layer.lat = 43.2356
56             point_layer.lon = 71.082296
57         if ret == "HL25":
58             point_layer.lat = 42.914089
59             point_layer.lon = 71.610217
60         if ret == "MR6":
61             point_layer.lat = 43.52
62             point_layer.lon = 71.819
63         if ret == "RC29":
64             point_layer.lat = 42.9007
65             point_layer.lon = 71.192591
66         if ret == "CH4":
67             point_layer.lat = 42.9395
68             point_layer.lon = 72.3284
69         if ret == "CR7":
70             point_layer.lat = 43.929483
71             point_layer.lon = 71.084079
72         if ret == "CS10":
73             point_layer.lat = 44.388238
74             point_layer.lon = 71.269535
75         if ret == "HL48":
76             point_layer.lat = 42.776745
77             point_layer.lon = 71.77992
78         point_layer.site = ret
79         point_layer.geometry = Point( float( point_layer.lon ), float (point_layer.lat ) )
80         size += 1
81         point_layer.get( pk=1 ).save( commit = False )
```

views.py

```
1 from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
2 from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
3 from django.template import RequestContext
4 from models import *
5 from apps.pages.models import DataEntry
6 
7 def map( request ):
8     return render_to_response('map/map.html',{},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
9 
10 def rebuild( request ):
11     import imports
12     imports.add_points()
13     return HttpResponseRedirect( '/map/' )
14 
15 def all( request ):
16     points = PointLayer.objects.all(a).kml()
17     return render_to_response("kml/main.kml", {
18         'geometries': points
19     }, context_instance=RequestContext( request ))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might be the problem: `point_layer.snow_Depth = this_data_entry.snow_Depth`. Try to see whether `this_data_entry.snow_Depth` is actually set.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Blender. It is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but your immediate error is from this line:

`point_layer = point_layers.create( pk=size )`

When you use [`create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#create), you need to make sure all required fields for the model are passed into the method since it creates *and saves* the object.

Since you are not passing a required field `snow_Depth`, it fails when it tries to save.

You can either pass all the required fields to `create`, or set them manually then save the object:

```
point_layer = PointLayer()
point_layer.pk = size
# .. other various fields
# Replace point_layer.get( pk=1 ).save( commit = False ) with:
point_layer.save()
```

The above solves your problem, but...

I think you might be trying to update some `PointLayer` objects - from your last line `point_layer.get( pk=1 ).save( commit = False )`

If that's the case, then you really want to replace:

`point_layer = point_layers.create( pk=size )` with:

`point_layer = PointLayer.objects.get(pk=size)`

However, since you have *deleted* all the objects with this line `PointLayer.objects.all().delete()`, perhaps that's not the case.

Clarify what you intend to do.

Comment: Thank you, I worked off of your answer and now it works. Thanks!